# Sort array of object on a property but keep the objects first for which property is missing

Tags: javascript, node.js, sorting

Here is an example

```
testWidgetOrderSort = [
        { "_id": "name", "order": 1 },
        { "_id": "is", "order": 2 },
        { "_id": "my", "order": 0 },
        { "_id": "oh I would be very first" },
        { "_id": "adam", "order": 3 }

      ]
```

Here for the the object { "_id": "oh I would be very first" } does not have the property order so it should come first.
And then the rest of the objects should be sorted according to the property "order"
So after sorting it should be,

```
 output= [ { _id: 'oh I would be very first' },
      { _id: 'my', order: 0 },
      { _id: 'name', order: 1 },
      { _id: 'is', order: 2 },
      { _id: 'adam', order: 3 } ]
```

Comment: If a comes before b, return -1, if b comes before a, return 1, otherwise check additional cases (HINT: `if`/`else if`/`else` is a clear pattern to follow for this).

Comment: Have you tried writing your custom sort logic when [sorting your array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-objects-by-property-values)?  What did you try and what didn't work?

Comment: Hint 2: if `order` is `undefined`, it comes before an `order` that is not undefined.

Comment: I wrote a logic to sort using order but for objects where order is missing it is adding them in the end.
function compare_order(a, b) {
          // a should come before b in the sorted order
          if (a.order < b.order) {
            return -1;
            // a should come after b in the sorted order
          } else if (a.order > b.order) {
            return 1;
            // a and b are the same
          } else {
            return 0;
          }
        }

Comment: If you don't care about performance too much, just create two arrays one without `order` (arr1) property and one with items having `order` (arr2) property. Push the items of arr1 to finalArr, then sort the items in arr2 and push it to finalArr.

Comment: @Avelanche I thought I was pretty clear, if `undefined` for `order` should come first, that should be your first check. Instead, you leave one or the other as "don't change the order" (undefined > 1 is false, 1 > undefined is false).

Comment: Also, put the code you've tried *in the body of the question* and not as a comment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort javascript array of objects by child properties (which may be missing)](//stackoverflow.com/q/29058568/90527)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Logic is basic array sorting logic.

- If both `a.order` and `b.order` are defined return 1 or -1 depending on the largest value.
- If either one of them is undefined return 1 or -1 depending on the defined value.

- **Please Note**: The value `1` and `-1` determines the relative position between the two nodes. Returning `1` places `a` after `b` and `-1` places `a` before `b`.

```js
const testWidgetOrderSort = [
  { "_id": "name", "order": 1 },
  { "_id": "is", "order": 2 },
  { "_id": "my", "order": 0 },
  { "_id": "oh I would be very first" },
  { "_id": "adam", "order": 3 }
];
const output = testWidgetOrderSort.sort((a, b) => {
  if( a.order !== undefined && b.order !== undefined ) {
    return a.order > b.order ? 1 : -1;
  } else {
    return a.order !== undefined ? 1 : -1
  }
});
console.log(output);
```

Comment: The [comma](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) in that `if` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: @crashmstr that was actually a typo and amajor bug. Thanks for pointing it out. I have fixed that in my code.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with something like this:

```js
const test = [
  { "_id": "name", "order": 1 },
  { "_id": "is", "order": 2 },
  { "_id": "my", "order": 0 },
  { "_id": "oh I would be very first" },
  { "_id": "adam", "order": 3 }
];

const x = test.sort((a, b) => {
  const [STAY, SWAP] = [-1, 1];
  if (!a.hasOwnProperty('order')) { return STAY; }
  if (!b.hasOwnProperty('order')) { return SWAP; }
  return a.order - b.order;
});

console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to pass the custom comparator function

```
if (!("order" in a)) return -1;
if (!("order" in b)) return 1;
else return a.order - b.order;
```

**1)** return `-1` if property `order` doesn't exist in `a`.

**2)** return `1` if property `order` doesn't exist in `b`.

**3)** if both the object has `order` property then just sort in ascending order.

```js
const arr = [
  { _id: "name", order: 1 },
  { _id: "is", order: 2 },
  { _id: "my", order: 0 },
  { _id: "oh I would be very first" },
  { _id: "adam", order: 3 },
];

const result = arr.sort((a, b) => {
  if (!("order" in a)) return -1;
  if (!("order" in b)) return 1;
  else return a.order - b.order;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Not an issue here, but usually using `Object.protoype.hasOwnProperty` instead of `key in` is the best practice to avoid searching through prototype chaining,

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the performance too much, the below should be fine,

```js
const testWidgetOrderSort = [
  { "_id": "name", "order": 1 },
  { "_id": "is", "order": 2 },
  { "_id": "my", "order": 0 },
  { "_id": "oh I would be very first" },
  { "_id": "adam", "order": 3 }

];

const finalArr = testWidgetOrderSort.filter(a => typeof a.order === "undefined");

const sortedArrWithOrderItems = testWidgetOrderSort.filter(a => typeof a.order !== "undefined").sort((a,b) => (a.order > b.order ? 1 : -1));

finalArr.push(...sortedArrWithOrderItems);

console.log(finalArr);
```

Note: Personally I would recommend going with @Nitheesh or @decpk solution, it is more clean and performance wise better. My solution is just to give another solution for the problem